# how to check a multiple conditional isset expression for true values?

Tags: php, isset

I've got a question about isset() with multiple conditionals, and checking to make sure they return non-null or correct results.

I'm trying to troubleshoot an isset expression that looks like:

```
if(isset($content['field_1']) && $content['field_2'] && $content['field_3']=="top"){
    do a thing
}
```

I understand that if field_1 is true, then the other conditionals are treated as true.

My "if" statement is looped thorugh a few times as a slideshow is being created.
Most of the slide created have all true resuults and are fine, but there are a couple slides where the value exists but not exactly as required.
The code works, but the drupal error log gets filled warnings of "undefined index".

The question I have is:
What is the best way to have a multiple conditional isset while proofing each section?
a simple "else" after the "if" isn't solving this since it's multiple conditionals (I think). and I don't know if there is an easier way to handle this than breaking the multiple conditionals into single ones before continuing.

If anyone kind enough to read this has questions, or if my question is not clear pelase let me know. I'm happy to clarify.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you maybe post an example of the multiple conditions ?

Comment: *"I understand that if field_1 is true, then the other conditionals are treated as true."* - not quite: if `$content['field_1']` is not set, then the condtion is false, and there is no need to evaluate the other two.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that if field_1 is true, then the other conditionals are treated as true.

Your assumption is wrong. You do not check value of `$content` referenced by key `field_1`, you check if such key exsits - these are two different things. Also you use `&&` (AND) operator, and in such case if one condition returns `false` then evaluating remaining is pointless as by the boolean logic the whole expression will be `false`.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's a great help! Now I have a better understand of where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ((!empty($content['field_1']) || !empty($content['field_2'])) && !empty($content['field_3']) && $content['field_3'] == 'top') {
    // Do Something
}
```